# После перехода из основного активти в другое и обратно, в основном активити обнуляются данные

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-sdk

Есть основное активити, когда из него перехожу в другое и возвращаюсь обратно, данные в основном активити обнуляются.

Единственное что приходит в голову это передать через putExtra (попробовал получилось), но мне кажется это не правильное решение туда-сюда гонять данные (из основного активити в другое, а потом те же самые данные из другого в основное).

метод onBackPressed(); срабатывает как надо, пока на свою кнопку "назад" поставил это метод, но это тоже мне кажется не правильным. Спасибо

основное активити

```
package com.example.testappv1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView upgrade_img;
    private ImageView men_level_img;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ConstraintLayout baseFonClicker;
    private TextView money_text;
    private TextView level_text;
    private int countMoney = 0;
    private int countProgress = 0;
    private int countLevel = 1;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        upgrade_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upgrade_img);
        men_level_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.men_level_img);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(10000);
        money_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money_text);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
        level_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level_text);
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        baseFonClicker = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.basefonclicker);

        baseFonClicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (countLevel == 1) { LevelOne(); }
                if (countLevel == 2) { LevelTwo(); }
                if (countLevel == 3) { LevelThree(); }
                if (countLevel == 4) { LevelFour(); }
                if (countLevel == 5) { LevelFive(); }
                if (countLevel == 6) { LevelSix(); }
                if (countLevel == 7) { LevelSeven(); }
                if (countLevel == 8) { LevelEight(); }
                if (countLevel == 9) { LevelNine(); }
                if (countLevel == 10) { LevelTen(); }
            }
        });

        upgrade_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpgradeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("level", level_text.getText());
                intent.putExtra("money", money_text.getText());
                intent.putExtra("progress", progressBar.getAutofillValue());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void postProgress(int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);

        if (progressBar.getProgress() >= progressBar.getMax()) {
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            countProgress = 0;
            countLevel++;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelOne() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        countMoney++;
        countProgress = countProgress + 1000;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelTwo() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb2l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 2;
        countProgress = countProgress + 900;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelThree() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb3l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 3;
        countProgress = countProgress + 800;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelFour() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb4l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 4;
        countProgress = countProgress + 700;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelFive() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb5l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 5;
        countProgress = countProgress + 600;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelSix() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb6l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 6;
        countProgress = countProgress + 500;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelSeven() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb7l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 7;
        countProgress = countProgress + 400;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelEight() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb8l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 8;
        countProgress = countProgress + 300;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelNine() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb9l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 9;
        countProgress = countProgress + 200;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelTen() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb10l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 10;
        countProgress = countProgress + 100;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }
```

}
а это другое активити

```
public class UpgradeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView back_view;
    private TextView level_text;
    private TextView money_text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upgrade);

        level_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level_text);
        back_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.back_view);
        money_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money_text);

        level_text.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("level"));
        money_text.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("money"));

        back_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: А что именно у Вас теряется-то? Ну а вообще, данные обычно сохраняют в `onSveInstanceState`...

Comment: level_text отображает уровень, когда из другого активити возвращюсь в основное снова 1, money_text отображает койны тоже становится равень 0 и progressBar пустой , добавил основное активити, может поможет

Comment: Ну да, Вам просто нужно сохранять состояние. Проверьте, то же самое будет при повороте экрана (в смысле сброса значений). Должно быть по крайней мере)

Comment: Да, при повороте экрана тоже самое, пойду гуглит про onSveInstanceState, большое спасибо

Comment: ты в отладчике поставь брейкпонит в метод OnCreate() если после перехода в новую активность и возврату назад он у тебя сработает повторно, то учи лайфсайкл. или сделай так чтобы приложение не вызывало OnCreate повторно.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/493802/

Comment: этот [способ более правильный](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/133-urok-70-onsaveinstancestate-sohranenie-dannyh-activity-pri-povorote-ekrana.html), чем предложенный @Yakov, так как никакой из режимов launch mode не гарантирует сохранение активити, которая не находится на переднем плане, всегда есть вероятнтсть, что активити в фоне может быть уничтожена и данные утрачены. Поэтому промежуточные  динамические данные (нужны на одну сессию) сохраняются в Bundle через onSaveInstanceState() а постоянные (нужны и между запусками приложения) в SharedPreferences, базу данных или файл

Comment: @pavlofff эти методы итак сохраняют состояние всех элементов в активности. даже если их не перегружать, проблема в том что, когда ты вращаешь экран или вызываешь новую активность, то при возврате в старую у тебя может быть вызван метод OnCreate, в котором в 90% создается заново из хмл активность через setContentView(), в случае когда активность долго находится в фоне она конечно может быть завершена, но в данном случае это мало вероятно, т.к. другая активность этого процесса активна. иногда android:launchMode="singleInstance" необходимость, и всего лишь один из предложенных вариантов.

Comment: @pavlofff вот у меня в приложении при запуске из бд в словарь загружается ~5-40 тысяч записей (в зависимости от сервера куда он подключен), как ты думаешь обрадуется пользователь приложения если он после поворота экрана будет 5 минут ждать повторной загрузки данных?

Comment: Теста ради сделал новый проект с апи 23. 2 активности. 2 эдита на них. в первой пишу текст. вызываю вторую, закрываю ее через finish(). текст в первой не пропадает. OnCreate() повторно не вызывается. может ты что-то намудрил в коде своем? или у тебя нет id у твоих UI-контролов?

Comment: @Yakov сохраняют состояние не всех элементов, а только состояние View имеющих id, переменные, массивы, коллекции и проч. динамические данные автоматически не сохраняются. *.. при возврате в старую у тебя может быть.. * весь жизненный цикл подробно описан в локументации, в том числе и то, что **должно** быть в каждом конкретном случае. При правильной работе с БД (а это прямые запросы в базу и обработка "сырых" выборок БД (Cursor), а не дилетанский подход с сохранением всех данных в коллекцию или массив) скорость получения данных из базы намного выше комфортного ожидания пользователя.

Comment: для "ленивых" есть Architecture Components включающий Room и LiveData. Если все просто бросить на самотек, у вас может 50 раз не пропасть данные, а на 51 пропадут и пользователь совершенно справедливо решит, что приложение глючное. Вообще все рабочие и проверенные практики изложены в любом мало мальски годном учебнике по разработке под android (напр. Б. Филлипс), но кто их читает...

Comment: @pavlofff вот ты критикуешь приложение кода которого не видел. с чего ты взял что однократная загрузка в LongSparseArray 40к записей и потом поиск значения в этом массиве работает медленнее чем 50 запросов в БД с теми-же 40к записей? когда я начинал проект румом/лайвдата еще и не пахло. а переделывать весь код после выхода новой фичи раз в полгода меня не тянет.

Comment: @pavlofff P.S. Мое приложение хранит данные в обычной бд на SQLite, но есть таблица где хранятся идентификаторы пары ключ и значение, и вот их очень много и загрузка и подстановка расшифровок в 10ки если не сотни раз быстрее работает через массив в памяти, чем чтение каждой пары ключ / значение из бд, ты вот хоть тресни не убедишь меня что найдется орм которая будет делать это быстрее, чем батч рид из бд и сохранение, как ты говоришь, дилетантами в массив в памяти.